# Is there a plugin or tool for multiple "profiles" in ZSH?

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, oh-my-zsh

I use oh-my-zsh for all of my console goodness.  Depending on what I'm working on, there are certain environment variables that I'm often overwriting either manually or through scripts to make my work easier for the next hour.  For example: setting default ssh identify files, changing the `AWS_PROFILE` env variable, clearing or resetting other custom environment variables.

I'd like to be able to switch to a different "environment" within a shell session based on some context, similar to how tools like `RubyEnv` and `PyEnv` work. Is there an easier way to do this in ZSH, either through a plugin or feature?

Comment: There is [zsh-autoenv](https://github.com/Tarrasch/zsh-autoenv), which uses `.autoenv.zsh` and `.autoenv_leave.zsh` to handle enabling and disabling of different environment settings.

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317720/is-there-a-plugin-or-tool-for-multiple-profiles-in-zsh#comment670887_317720) mentions `zsh-autoenv`, but [it does not appear to be maintained anymore](https://github.com/Tarrasch/zsh-autoenv/graphs/code-frequency).

I would recommend using [`direnv`](https://github.com/direnv/direnv) instead. It [comes with Zsh support](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/blob/master/docs/hook.md).